# Eclipse will not Work?

Tags: java, eclipse, development-environment

I have two different versions of eclipse that both quit working on me, I am using windows 7 home premium, the versions of eclipse that I have are Eclipse Luna 4.4 and Eclipse Juno. I have done the following things to correct the error but I am not getting a crash report or anything. In the following order I have tried:

```
Restarting my computer,
Deleting eclipse and reinstalling,

From command running 
Eclipse.exe -clean
Eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState
Eclipse.exe -debug

I have also checked my JAVA_HOME environment variable which is properly set, and the PATH       environment
Variable which is also properly set. Still not sure what is going on.

:::EDIT:::
Ok I did Find a report on my windows compatibility checker saying that the application
is incompatible with windows and the repair the issue section failed to repair it.
I do know that two days ago I was working in the eclipse environment without a problem.
When I got home yesterday my machine showed that there had been new updates installed. I
didn't have any issues until yesterday. So I guess my next question is how do I find what 
made the application incompatible with my machine, and if it was the updates how do I reverse 
them so that I can get my IDE back, I could switch to Netbeans But I prefer to not have to do
so It just doesn't make any sense to do so if I could somehow manage to get eclipse working
again.
```

all give me the same result, a quick flicker of what I imagine is the Eclipse splash screen and that is it, so my question is where might I find a crash or debug report (if one is generated by eclipse) other wise does any on have any idea what may be happening.

Comment: The log file must be with the eclipse directory, one with eclipse.exe

Comment: @Nabin I can't find a log file in any directory within the eclipse folder or in the main eclipse directory

Comment: Start eclipsesec.exe from console an paste output.

Comment: No output same issue a flicker and then dead

Comment: If there were only a strace/dtrace that came with Windows. :)

Comment: @Nabin I have tried running eclipse.exe and eclipse from the command prompt with -console I am still getting the same thing, the console box will popup with the eclipse splash screen and then quickly disappear. I have found an incompatibility report that doesn't give any details as to what has caused it to be incompatible. It has also failed to repair the issue, also I think that this was brought on by a windows update, because the application worked the day before this issue started and now it doesn't. Is there a way to reverse a particular patch of updates?

Answer (score 0):

THANKS..

Running Eclipse
After installing the Eclipse SDK in a directory, you can start the Workbench by running the Eclipse executable included with the release (you also need at least a JDK6 or JRE 6, not included with the Eclipse SDK). On Windows, the executable file is called eclipse.exe, and is located in the eclipse sub-directory of the install. If installed at c:\eclipse-SDK-4.4-win32, the executable is c:\eclipse-SDK-4.4-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe. Note: Set-up on most other operating environments is analogous. Special instructions for Mac OS X are listed below.

Allocating enough memory and solving OutOfMemoryErrors
By default, Eclipse will allocate up to 384 megabytes of Java heap memory. This should be ample for all typical development tasks. However, depending on the JRE that you are running, the number of additional plug-ins you are using, and the number of files you will be working with, you could conceivably have to increase this amount. Eclipse allows you to pass arguments directly to the Java VM using the -vmargs command line argument, which must follow all other Eclipse specific arguments. Thus, to increase the available heap memory, you would typically use:

eclipse -vmargs -Xmx

with the  value set to greater than "384M" (384 megabytes -- the default).

When using an Oracle JRE, you may also need to increase the size of the permanent generation memory. The default maximum is 64 megabytes, but more may be needed depending on your plug-in configuration and use. When the VM runs out of permanent generation memory, it may crash or hang during class loading. The maximum permanent generation size is increased using the -XX:MaxPermSize= argument:

eclipse -vmargs -XX:MaxPermSize=

This argument may not be available for all VM versions and platforms; consult your VM documentation for more details.

Note that setting memory sizes to be larger than the amount of available physical memory on your machine will cause Java to "thrash" as it copies objects back and forth to virtual memory, which will severely degrade your performance.

Selecting a workspace
When the Workbench is launched, the first thing you see is a dialog that allows you to select where the workspace will be located. The workspace is the directory where your work will be stored. If you do not specify otherwise, Eclipse creates the workspace in your user directory. This workspace directory is used as the default content area for your projects as well as for holding any required metadata. For shared or multi-workspace installs you must explicitly specify the location for your workspace using the dialog (or via the "-data" command line argument).

Specifying the Java virtual machine
Here is a typical Eclipse command line:

eclipse -vm c:\jdk7u45\jre\bin\javaw

Tip: It's generally a good idea to explicitly specify which Java VM to use when running Eclipse. This is achieved with the "-vm" command line argument as illustrated above. If you don't use "-vm", Eclipse will look on the O/S path. When you install other Java-based products, they may change your path and could result in a different Java VM being used when you next launch Eclipse.

To create a Windows shortcut to an installed Eclipse:

Navigate to eclipse.exe in Windows Explorer and use Create Shortcut on the content menu.
Select the shortcut and edit its Properties. In the Target: field append the command line arguments.
Opening this shortcut launches Eclipse. (You can drag the shortcut to the Windows Desktop if you want to keep it in easy reach.)

Mac OS X
On Mac OS X, you start Eclipse by double clicking the Eclipse application. If you need to pass arguments to Eclipse, you'll have to edit the eclipse.ini file inside the Eclipse application bundle: select the Eclipse application bundle icon while holding down the Control Key. This will present you with a popup menu. Select "Show Package Contents" in the popup menu. Locate eclipse.ini file in the Contents/MacOS sub-folder and open it with your favorite text editor to edit the command line options.

On MacOS X you can only launch a UI program more than once if you have separate copies of the program on disk. The reason for this behavior is that every UI application on Mac can open multiple documents, so typically there is no need to open a program twice. Since Eclipse cannot open more than one workspace, this means you have to make a copy of the Eclipse install if you want to open more then one workspace at the same time (bug 139319).

If you need to launch Eclipse from the command line, you can use the symbolic link "eclipse" in the top-level eclipse folder. It refers to the eclipse executable inside the application bundle and takes the same arguments as "eclipse.exe" on other platforms.

On Mac OS X 10.4 and later, you may notice a slow down when working with significant numbers of resources if you allow Spotlight to index your workspace. To prevent this, start System Preferences, select the Spotlight icon, then the Privacy tab, then click the Add button ("+") and find your workspace directory in the dialog that appears.

Shared Install
The startup speed of a shared install can be improved if proper cache information is stored in the shared install area. To achieve this, after unzipping Eclipse distribution, run Eclipse once with the "-initialize" option from an account that has a write access to the install directory.

Comment: I have tried adding heap size although I find it unnecessary being that the eclipse version was at once working fine, I have only one application in the workspace and no plugins. The IDE was working well yesterday I came home today to use it and it wouldn't start, only flicker and then go away. I have tried all of the obvious work arounds and still got nothing. I have tried using the executable shortcut in the eclipse directory as well as running from command with "eclipse" and eclipse.exe along with the commands I have given above in the question. I have used eclipse for years never had this

Comment: happen before in any of the instances of the application I have used